# Color change not working when i open file

Tags: java, swing, file, jtextpane, foreground

I'm working on a notepad program and I have it where as the user types, if a certain word is typed (ex: public, void, private, protected, static), the color changes to a dark red color (like in eclipse), but if the user opens a file, it doesn't change the color and even as the user typed, nothing happens. It only works when typing into a "new" document. This is a short version of my project of everything that is necessary:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultStyledDocument;
import javax.swing.text.SimpleAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import javax.swing.text.StyleContext;

public class Test {
    static JTabbedPane tabbedPane;
    static JTextPane txt;

    private static int findLastNonWordChar(String text, int index) {
        while (--index >= 0) {
            if (String.valueOf(text.charAt(index)).matches("\\W")) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return index;
    }

    private static int findFirstNonWordChar(String text, int index) {
        while (index < text.length()) {
            if (String.valueOf(text.charAt(index)).matches("\\W")) {
                break;
            }
            index++;
        }
        return index;
    }

    private static void makeBold(SimpleAttributeSet sas) {
        sas.addAttribute(StyleConstants.CharacterConstants.Bold, Boolean.TRUE);
    }

    private static void makeUnBold(SimpleAttributeSet sas) {
        sas.addAttribute(StyleConstants.CharacterConstants.Bold, Boolean.FALSE);
    }

    private static JTextPane createEmptyDocument() {
        final StyleContext cont = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext();
        final AttributeSet attrRed = cont.addAttribute(cont.getEmptySet(), StyleConstants.Foreground, new Color(127, 0, 85));
        final AttributeSet attrBlack = cont.addAttribute(cont.getEmptySet(), StyleConstants.Foreground, Color.BLACK);
        SimpleAttributeSet sas = new SimpleAttributeSet();

        DefaultStyledDocument document = new DefaultStyledDocument() {
            public void insertString(int offset, String str, AttributeSet a) throws BadLocationException {
                super.insertString(offset, str, a);

                String text = getText(0, getLength());
                int before = findLastNonWordChar(text, offset);
                if (before < 0) before = 0;
                int after = findFirstNonWordChar(text, offset + str.length());
                int wordL = before;
                int wordR = before;

                while (wordR <= after) {
                    if (wordR == after || String.valueOf(text.charAt(wordR)).matches("\\W")) {
                        if (text.substring(wordL, wordR).matches("(\\W)*(public|static|void|main|private|protected)")) {
                            setCharacterAttributes(wordL, wordR - wordL, attrRed, false);
                            makeBold(sas);
                            setCharacterAttributes(wordL, wordR - wordL, sas, false);
                        } else {
                            setCharacterAttributes(wordL, wordR - wordL, attrBlack, false);
                            makeUnBold(sas);
                            setCharacterAttributes(wordL, wordR - wordL, sas, false);
                        }
                        wordL = wordR;
                    }
                    wordR++;
                }
            }

            public void remove(int offs, int len) throws BadLocationException {
                super.remove(offs, len);

                String text = getText(0, getLength());
                int before = findLastNonWordChar(text, offs);
                if (before < 0) before = 0;
                int after = findFirstNonWordChar(text, offs);

                if (text.substring(before, after).matches("(\\W)*(public|static|void|private|protected)")) {
                    makeBold(sas);
                    setCharacterAttributes(before, after - before, attrRed, false);
                    setCharacterAttributes(before, after - before, sas, false);
                } else {
                    makeUnBold(sas);
                    setCharacterAttributes(before, after - before, attrBlack, false);
                    setCharacterAttributes(before, after - before, sas, false);
                }
            }
        };
        return new JTextPane(document);
    }

    private static void readInFile(File file, JTextPane txt) {
        try {
            FileReader r = new FileReader(file);
            txt.read(r, null);
            r.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void createNewDocument(File file, JTabbedPane tabbedPane) {
        txt = createEmptyDocument();

        String fileName;
        String theFile;

        if (file == null) {
            fileName = "Untitled";
            theFile = "Untitled";
        } else {
            fileName = file.getName().toString();
            theFile = file.toString();

            readInFile(file, txt);
        }

        txt.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 14));

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(txt);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(scrollPane);
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));

        tabbedPane.addTab(fileName, null, panel, theFile);
        tabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(tabbedPane.getTabCount() - 1);

        tabbedPane.setFocusable(false);
        txt.grabFocus();
    }

    private static JTabbedPane setupForTabs(JFrame frame) {
        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();

        topPanel.add(tabbedPane);
        frame.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        return tabbedPane;
    }

    static Action New = new AbstractAction("New") {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            createNewDocument(null, tabbedPane);
        }
    };

    static Action Open = new AbstractAction("Open") {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            int result = chooser.showOpenDialog(tabbedPane);

            if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                createNewDocument(file, tabbedPane);
            }
        }
    };

    private static JMenuBar createMenuBar(JTabbedPane tabbedPane) {
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu file = new JMenu("File");

        JMenuItem newDoc = new JMenuItem();
        JMenuItem open = new JMenuItem();

        New.putValue(Action.ACCELERATOR_KEY, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_N, KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK));
        newDoc.setAction(New);

        Open.putValue(Action.ACCELERATOR_KEY, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_O, KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK));
        open.setAction(Open);

        menuBar.add(file);

        file.add(newDoc);
        file.add(open);

        return menuBar;
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Notepad");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);

        tabbedPane = setupForTabs(frame);

        createNewDocument(null, tabbedPane);

        JMenuBar menuBar = createMenuBar(tabbedPane);
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        frame.pack();

        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        frame.setLocation(dim.width/2-frame.getSize().width/2, dim.height/2-frame.getSize().height/2);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                UIManager.put("swing.boldmetal", Boolean.FALSE);
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I need those keywords to have their color changed, even when opening a file. Right now I don't have a method to search for the words after the file is opened, but I'm worrying about having the color change as the user types in an opened document. If anyone could give me a hint on how to search for the words and change the color after the file is opened, that would be great also. :)

Comment: 1) See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing. 2) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant. 3) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow!

Comment: Didn't realize there was a hanging bracket. My apologies.

Answer (score 2):

The `read(...)` method creates a new `PlainDocument` when it reads the text file.

Instead of creating an anonymous inner class create a custom class for your Document, maybe "ColoredDocument".

Then you can use code like the following:

```
EditorKit editorKit = new StyledEditorKit()
{
    public Document createDefaultDocument()
    {
        return new ColoredDocument();
    }
};

JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
textPane.setEditorKit( editorKit );

FileReader fr = new FileReader( ... );
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( fr );
textPane.read( br, null );
```